# How do you LINK back to Word press HTML pages CORRECTLY

Tags: html, css, wordpress, syntax, template-specialization

Iv'e imported my html FILES folder
consisting of
index.html
& FOLDER with the css, & js, Other files such as images
EX:
PATH dedeluxe.shop/index.html

when typed in browser loads the html page but has no WORDPRESS ASSOC Page.
Please direct me to next step if poss?

1. i didnt create a new theme
2. i didnt create a new.php, .css, .js files

Comment: Sounds like you're not really familiar with WordPress in general so it might be a good idea to check the official [developer documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/) to learn how to create WordPress themes and use your custom HTML with them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.